# UIDatePicker Exception when calling setDatePickerMode with Region Format set to Taiwan Calendar to Japanese

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uidatepicker

We are using the standard UIDatePicker view to allow the user to set a countdown duration using the picker. The code is as follows:

```
//in the header file
UIDatePicker *pickerView;

//in the implementation file, the error is thrown when this line executes
[self.pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];
```

This works fine in most circumstances, however we have a user who has their region format set to Taiwan and their Calendar to Japanese. The following exception then occurs:

> 2011-05-08 21:38:13.701
>   AppName[6418:207] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[UIDatePickerView
>   _updateRowInColumn:toValue:withRepeatingAmount:element:animated:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UIDatePicker.m:1499
>   2011-05-08 21:38:13.703
>   AppName[6418:207]**  Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'whoa! too many rows for
>   column: 1'
>   ** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00fa3be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x010f85c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>     2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00f5c628 +[NSException
>   raise:format:arguments:] + 136    3
>   Foundation
>   0x000d447b -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
>   + 116     4   UIKit                               0x004b1e4e -[UIDatePickerView
>   _updateRowInColumn:toValue:withRepeatingAmount:element:animated:]
>   + 695     5   UIKit                               0x004b5254 -[UIDatePickerView
>   _loadDateAnimated:] + 1012

Does anyone have any experience with the above error or how to work around this? It seems like there is a problem with the Gregorian vs non Gregorian operation of this component. From what I understood the component takes the user's settings if no default is provided:

From UIDatePicker.h:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSLocale      *locale;                // default is nil. use current locale or locale from calendar
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSTimeZone    *timeZone;              // default is nil. use current time zone or time zone from calendar
@property(nonatomic,copy)   NSCalendar    *calendar;              // default is [NSCalendar currentCalendar]. setting nil returns to default
```

Comment: We have raised this issue as a bug with Apple and will add an answer to the thread once we receive a response

Comment: I had this error show up when i tried to pass in a really wrong date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was previously a bug which is now resolved with the release of iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

have you created a property for your instance variable pickerView? Since you have not mentioned it in the question, I am wondering how you are accessing the setter methods for the pickerView without creating a property like @property(nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker *pickerView;

Comment: If we didn't have the above in the header file the code wouldn't compile. (Also note that the code works for most circumstances, just not these specific Region Formats and Calendar configurations). The reason I put the variable type in the above example was to make it clear what pickerView was in code. The bug has been filed under Apple's bug reporting process.